# How can I get the rest of a django-registration password reset form?

Tags: python, django, url, django-forms, django-registration

I found a mostly complete set of templates for the django-registration package, but the password reset page is incomplete. The file has only:

```
{{ form }}
```

which expands to:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td><input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

I can supply the missing TABLE tag, but I don't know what to supply for the action on the missing FORM tag.

(I tried to look through the URLs.py, and found the following which seems relevant, but I don't quite see how to reconstruct what I want, the specific value for the form action.)

```
                   #url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                       #auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
```

Suggestions for how to fill this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant view for the password reset form can be found here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/9af7e18f3579df18625b9eda70735790f23aeb96/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L133

Answer (score 0):

**django-registration** reset password only display you email field.you have to submit form by filling email address and after submit this form you will get a mail filled email address with a link you can click on that link you will get page for reset password enter new passwords and submit form.